# Convert Raw Vector into a Parameterized Vector

Tags: java, generics

I heard that it is a good practice to use parameterized vectors whenever you can, so I have a super class, one of whose methods return a raw vector, which I want to add it to my String parameterized Vector.

```
Vector<String> paramVector = new Vector<String> ();
paramVector = Superclass.somemethod(textfield.gettext); //Returns a raw vector
```

This code gives a warning that it needs unchecked conversion, I'd like to do the same i.e., convert the raw vector into parameterized one while assigning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})`, but using this code would be safer:

```
Vector rawVector = Superclass.somemethod(textfield.gettext);
Vector<String> paramVector = new Vector<String> ();

for(Object obj : rawVector)
{
   if(obj instanceof String)
      paramVector.add(obj);
}
```

Comment: So there's no way of casting a raw vector directly to a parameterized vector while assigning?

Comment: @Cybermonk raw vector doesn't specify the type of the objects it contains, that's why we use generics. you can assign and cast a raw vector to the parametrized one, but you will get a warning from compiler. You can either suppress warning or use the loop above to safely add entries to your parametrized vector..